# How to run Jetty with SPDY on JDK8?

Tags: java, jetty, java-8, spdy

For a few days we have JDK8. I have tried to run Jetty with SPDY server. In JDK8 there is no NPN support so it ends with:

```
[qtp22068985-16-selector-ServerConnectorManager@12e7b0e/1] WARN
org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Exception while notifying connection SslConnection@e1448a{NEED_UNWRAP,eio=-1/-1,di=-1} ->
NPNServerConnection@382d40{IDLE}
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
sun.security.ssl.HandshakeHash.<init>(ZZLjava/util/Set;)V
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:493)
```

I have run it with `npn-boot-1.1.6.v20130911.jar` on CLASSPATH which works with newest JDK7.

Is there any workaround on how to run Jetty with SPDY on JDK8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am the implementer of NPN in Jetty.

NPN is implemented by modifying the JDK classes for the lack of a TLS Extension API in the JDK. The NPN versions match strictly a JDK version as specified in the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/npn-chapter.html#npn-versions).

For JDK 8 we don't plan to support NPN. Instead, we will support ALPN which is the successor to NPN, and backport the ALPN implementation to JDK 7 too.

The implementations for ALPN are already done in a branch, but not integrated yet in the main Jetty build.

You have to be patient for a little while, we need to finalize a bunch of things and integrate ALPN in Jetty master. When that is done we'll [blog](https://webtide.intalio.com/) about.

Comment: I'm getting an exception using hotspot jdk1.8u40 `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.HandshakeHash.setCertificateVerifyAlg`. Does this only work on OpenJDK?

Comment: NPN is not supported for JDK 8, you have to use [ALPN](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html).