# How to run Jetty with SPDY using ALPN?

Tags: java, jetty, spdy, alpn

I have returned to JDK8 with Jetty and SPDY and I see that now Jetty 9.2 supports ALPN protocol instead of NPN (see my question [How to run Jetty with SPDY on JDK8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608892/how-to-run-jetty-with-spdy-on-jdk8)). So I set `bootclasspath`:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:c:/jars/alpn-boot/alpn-boot-8.0.0.v2014031 ...
```

But now I got exception:

```
Exception in thread "xyz.server" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
        org/eclipse/jetty/npn/NextProtoNego$ServerProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    ...
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.server.http.HTTPSPDYServerConnector.<init>(HTTPSPDYServerConnector.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.server.http.HTTPSPDYServerConnector.<init>(HTTPSPDYServerConnector.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.server.http.HTTPSPDYServerConnector.<init>(HTTPSPDYServerConnector.java:43)
    at xyz.my.my_httpsrv_jetty.startHTTPSServer(my_httpsrv_jetty.java:359)
    ...
```

I use `java version "1.8.0_05"` and jetty 9.2.2.v20140723.

The same error I got with JDK 1.7 and `alpn-boot-7.0.0.v20140317.jar` on WinXP where I changed if from `-Xbootclasspath/p:c:/jars/npn-boot/npn-boot-1.1.7.v20140316.jar`

This execption points in my code into:

```
SSLconnector = new HTTPSPDYServerConnector(server, sslContextFactory);
```

It seems that even with ALPN jetty needs classes from npn-boot.
Is it a bug or I have done something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HTTPSPDYServerConnector` was not updated to ALPN and currently hardcodes usage of NPN.

In order to use ALPN with SPDY you have to configure a `ServerConnector` instead in this way:

```java
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

SslConnectionFactory ssl = new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "alpn");
ALPNServerConnectionFactory alpn = new ALPNServerConnectionFactory("spdy/3", "http/1.1");
alpn.setDefaultProtocol("http/1.1");
HTTPSPDYServerConnectionFactory spdy = new HTTPSPDYServerConnectionFactory(SPDY.V3, httpConfig);
HttpConnectionFactory http = new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig);

Server server = new Server();
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new ConnectionFactory[]{ssl, alpn, spdy, http});

server.start();
```

I tracked this as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440756.

Finally, if you don't use the code directly, but use Jetty as a server and deploy webapps to it, Jetty already configures properly either ALPN or NPN depending on the modules that are activated.

Comment: OK. I edited my code and use this way of starting server and it seems to work with SPDY. Thanks!

Comment: It works but I have problems with client certificates. It is long so I have made other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972186/how-to-work-with-client-certificates-on-jetty-spdy-with-alpn