# How to work with client certificates on Jetty SPDY with ALPN?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, spdy, alpn

I have problem with client certifiacates when I use SPDY with Jetty.

It works when I work with NPN and start Jetty SPDY server with:

```
SSLconnector = new HTTPSPDYServerConnector(server, sslContextFactory);
```

As a `baseRequest.getHttpChannel()` it uses `org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.server.http.HttpChannelOverSPDY` and I can read SSL properties like `SSL_SESSION_ID` and client certificates with code like:

```
// ... HttpServletRequest request
java.security.cert.X509Certificate client_certs[] = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

But NPN is not an option in Java8 (see my question [How to run Jetty with SPDY using ALPN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035063/how-to-run-jetty-with-spdy-using-alpn/)). In Java8 I have to use ALPN protocol like:

```
sslContextFactory.setWantClientAuth(w3srv_config.want_client_auth);
// ...
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

SslConnectionFactory ssl = new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "alpn");
ALPNServerConnectionFactory alpn = new ALPNServerConnectionFactory("spdy/3", "http/1.1");
alpn.setDefaultProtocol("http/1.1");
HTTPSPDYServerConnectionFactory spdy = new HTTPSPDYServerConnectionFactory(SPDY.V3, httpConfig);
HttpConnectionFactory http = new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig);

SSLconnector = new ServerConnector(server, new ConnectionFactory[]{ssl, alpn, spdy, http});
//...
```

With this code I got `null` when I want to get any SSL related `javax.servlet.request.*`. Its `baseRequest.getHttpChannel()` is `org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$HttpChannelOverHttp`.

What I have to change to work with client certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.servlet.request.*` properties you are looking for are set by Jetty's `SecureRequestCustomizer`, which you need to add to the `httpConfig` object you create in your code example above.

I am guessing that your NPN configuration is slightly different, or you use some utility method in Jetty that does this for you with NPN but not with ALPN.

Just doing:

```java
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
```

should be enough to fix your issue.

Comment: I made some non-standard things like excluding some protocols but I have not configured NPN nor ALPN. I just change boot jar and change start code that is in my question. Anyway using `httpConfig.addCustomizer()` helped and now I see SSL properties, Thank you!