# Jetty: is it possible to use SPDY/3.1?

Tags: java, jetty, spdy

I run Jetty server using JDK 1.8 and ALPN as described at: [How to run Jetty with SPDY using ALPN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035063/how-to-run-jetty-with-spdy-using-alpn)

There is line:

```
ALPNServerConnectionFactory alpn = new ALPNServerConnectionFactory("spdy/3", "http/1.1");
```

and:

```
HTTPSPDYServerConnectionFactory spdy = new HTTPSPDYServerConnectionFactory(SPDY.V3, httpConfig, push);
```

But Chrome 40 uses only "spdy/3.1" and "http/1.1". With ALPN debug enabled it looks like:

```
[S] ALPN protocols [spdy/3.1, http/1.1] received from client for 1987cc45[SSLEngine[hostname=169.0.1.126 port=59439] SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
```

Negotiation ends with `http/1.1`. So I changed that line into:

```
ALPNServerConnectionFactory alpn = new ALPNServerConnectionFactory("spdy/3.1", "http/1.1");
```

This gives that `spdy/3.1` is selected:

```
[S] ALPN protocol 'spdy/3.1' selected for 1987cc45[SSLEngine[hostname=169.0.1.126 port=59439] SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
```

But Chrome does not receive response. I have not found any exception on the server side but it seems that Jetty cannot work with SPDY/3.1.

Can Jetty work with SPDY/3.1? How to set it?

I use JDK 1.8.0_31 and in bootstap `alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar`.

Comment: Update regarding SPDY on Jetty -> https://twitter.com/JettyProject/status/560828357424594946

Comment: Thanks. So I have to wait for Jetty 9.3 with HTTP/2 support and enable this protocol in Chrome. I see that this work on https://webtide.com/ :-)

Comment: Jetty 9.3 has HTTP/2 already. (that's the git master branch btw)

Comment: Another update on the future of SPDY (Chrome is deprecating it) - https://twitter.com/igrigorik/status/564850517071757314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty does not support `SPDY/3.1`, only up to `SPDY/3`.

In fact, Jetty will never support `SPDY/3.1`.

SPDY and NPN were just removed from the code tree in the upcoming Jetty 9.3.0 release.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/commit/?id=2162455b72d5a474bba47d5daf5543d46c2688be