# run Jetty with SPDY out-of-the-box

Tags: ssl, jetty, spdy

I switched from Tomcat to Jetty as ServletContainer and try to enable SPDY with all default settings of jetty. This are my steps to enable SPDY:

1. I download and unzip jetty
2. i copy a .war-File in webapps and some Deployment-Descriptors which are only project specific.
3. (now the tricky part) i enable SPDY by executing the following command:

   java -jar start.jar --add-to-startd=spdy

I accept the untrusted **protonego-impl** and now exist a **start.d/spdy.ini** file.

4. and now start jetty with:

   java -jar start.jar

Additionaly i enable some debugging by uncommenting in **etc/protonego-alpn.xml** the command:

```
<Set class="org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN" name="debug" type="boolean">true</Set>
```

On server startup i get:

> 2015-02-10 13:22:10.292:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5841a6a3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
>   2015-02-10 13:22:10.387:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5c9f2ea4{SSL-alpn}{0.0.0.0:8443}

Which tell me on Port 8080 runs normal HTTP and on 8443 run ALPN which support following protocols: spdy/3,spdy/2,http/1.1.
But if i visit a HTTPS page from my project i get following:

> [S] ALPN protocols [spdy/3.1, http/1.1] received from client for 783e3eb9[SSLEngine[hostname=127.0.0.1 port=50458] SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
>   [S] ALPN protocol 'http/1.1' selected for 783e3eb9[SSLEngine[hostname=127.0.0.1 port=50458] SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]

I understand the above statment that the server support spdy/3.1 and http/1.1 was selected. But remove all connections except spdy/3 i got EofExceptions and can't visit HTTPS pages.

I use Java JDK 1.7 and Chrome with SPDY-Indicator and Jetty 9.2.5 and all configurations over XML.
Can someone help me or tell more about this issue?
Oh and it's not required to use ALPN, i want spdy and the technique behind this is at the moment unnecessary.

Comment: I try the solution below after converting the code snipped in a xml config representation but i can't see a spdy connection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035063/how-to-run-jetty-with-spdy-using-alpn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty does not support `SPDY/3.1`, only up to `SPDY/3`.

In fact, Jetty will never support `SPDY/3.1`.

SPDY and NPN were just removed from the code tree in the upcoming Jetty 9.3.0 release.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/commit/?id=2162455b72d5a474bba47d5daf5543d46c2688be

Comment: OK. Its not required to use spdy/3.1. I want to use spdy and the direct Version isn't important. Have you an idea why i get no spdy connection?

Comment: @Happo the browser is negotiating spdy/3.1 and http/1.1, the server can speak spdy/3.0 and http/1.1, so the protocol negotiation chooses http/1.1 as the only protocol in common. 

If you want to rip the benefits of SPDY, I suggest you use HTTP/2 instead, since all browsers that support SPDY support also HTTP/2, and Jetty 9.3.0 also supports HTTP/2.