# SQLServer JDBC for Java 8

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc, jtds

I'm making the switch to **Java 8** on a project that uses SQLServer.

I tried **JDBC 4.0** with Java 8 and apparently it doesn't work (due to internal API changes it seems).

Do any of you have any idea if there's a planned JDBC release supporting Java 8? I've look up and didn't find anything...

Using **JTDS** doesn't seem to be an option since it's also giving some other errors.

EDIT:

Thanks for the feedback. The issue I'm having is the following:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.setSNIServerNames(Ljava/util/List;)V
>                                 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.initHandshaker(SSLSocketImpl.java:1301)
>                                 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect(SSLSocketImpl.java:671)
>                                 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.(SSLSocketImpl.java:551)
>                                 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:110)
>                                 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1606)

EDIT 2:

So I found the problem. It's NPN's fault:

[How to run Jetty with SPDY on JDK8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608892/how-to-run-jetty-with-spdy-on-jdk8)

Comment: We have been using JDBC in Java 8 with SQL Server, perhaps you need to try a different driver.

Comment: May i have a SQL Server version??

Comment: We're using Java 8 for integration tests for [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), both with jTDS and with sqljdbc4, without any issues. What particular errors are you getting?

Comment: The exception occurs inside Java internal implementation classes, and I'd think those would be internally consistent and only call existing methods. My guess is that your classpath (or `lib/ext`) contains an old JSSE library. The Java 8 library contains this method: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/ssl/Handshaker.java#452

Comment: You're right. I guess I was still in the mindset of "any-error-is-a-java-8-integration-bug". Still, I can't figure out what's going on...